# Dagger injection within JUnit TestRule

Tags: android, junit, dagger, android-espresso

While running an Espresso test on Android, is there any way to inject dependencies within a custom `TestRule`?

Answer (score -3):

why would you inject in Testcases? You should use DI when you need to pass instances in constructors... using this approach lets you mock those instances in testcases...

```
@Inject //Constructor getting injected instance
public classToBeTested(NewInstance instancenew){......}
```

If you test this class you can provide any mock-object to this class... This should be the way using DI...

Comment: I need to inject my okhttp client since I'd like to use `IdlingResources` within a Rule using this [library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/okhttp-idling-resource).
In any case that doesn't answer my question.